# Pair to Mac from a VS2019 Xamarin.Forms Project using Microsoft App Centre?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-app-center

I created a Xamarin.Forms App using VS2019 and successfully paired to a Hosted Mac Build Server running on MacInCloud.com so that I can locally debug and run my app on the iOS simulator. How do I 'Pair to Mac' on the Microsoft App Centre Build Server?

Comment: This is not a service offered by AppCenter.

Answer (score 0):

App Center build project in **[Cloud Machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/software)**, there is no option to **Pair to Mac** in App Center.

> Each build runs on a separate, clean virtual machine (VM) no one else has access to. Once the build completes, App Center discards the virtual machine, and all files removed. The artifacts resulting from the build (log files, application files, symbol files) are stored on App Center servers.

In addition, if you want to test project in some special devices, you could choose the service provided from App Center.

**[Starting a test run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/starting-a-test-run)** and here is the current supported **[App Center Test iOS Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/devices/ios)**.